# Action in Combat , Can I make a full attack with touch attacks for a trigger spell?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, combat, actions, character-levels

Myself and the other characters have 10 levels for templates or monster class and 8 levels for class levels, with [Divine Power](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Divine_Power) I gain a bab equal my character level. (18  right?).

I cast Shivering Touch spell first and 1 round after I make full attack with touch attack, so for my bab 18 I can do 4 attacks 18/15/10/5 .

Will anyone attack trigger Shivering Touch?

Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks for the wonderful work of this site.

Comment: Hi there. Just to clarify a bit, you have 8 class levels, and *10* levels of template level adjustments and monster hit dice? How many of each of those two things do you have? Also, your class levels are all Cleric levels? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Not normally. Activating a wand is either a standard action (core) or the same action it takes to cast the spell the wand holds (*Rules Compendium*). Even under *Rules Compendium*, I do not know of any spell that can be cast in place of an attack.<sup>1</sup>

That said, some touch-attack spells last for multiple touches; [*chill touch*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/chillTouch.htm) is the classic case of that. So you can cast it (including from a wand) as a standard action and touch once, but then on the subsequent turn you can full-attack with the charge, which will last. Unfortunately, that’s a rather rare property, and the only attack spells like that are all sorcerer/wizard spells. *Chill touch* itself appears on the Cold Domain, and *parching touch* appears in the Thirst Domain, so those are conceivable options for a cleric.

Note that *shivering touch* is **not** such a spell. The duration line on *shivering touch* is an error, or indicates that something else about the spell is in error, because it makes no sense there. But note the format of *chill touch*: it is Instantaneous, and the **Targets** line is the one to indicate that it can be used repeatedly. That is how this “multi-touch” property is indicated. *Shivering touch* does not have that. Since it deals damage, it should be Instantaneous, or perhaps it should apply a penalty rather than damage, which would have the indicated duration. Either way works; ask your DM. The former is extremely powerful; the latter is pretty solid without being ridiculous, and is therefore recommended.

Double Wand Wielder in *Complete Mage* allows you to dual-wield wands and use both at the same time in a full-round action (using 2 charges from each wand), but that’s hardly the same as a full-attack.

The 13th-level duskblade upgrade to their Arcane Channeling feature allows you to “cast” a single melee touch-range spell “you know” and apply it to all of your attacks in a full-attack action. I put quotes around those words because, as @Forrestfire recently discovered/pointed out to me, wands technically say you cast the spell within. If you also know the spell contained in the wand, you could arguably “cast” it from the wand for the sake of Arcane Channeling. That would require you to have 13 levels of duskblade, however.

<sup>1</sup> Well, in official material, anyway; I wrote a fairly popular homebrew class that did exactly that.

Comment: *Shivering touch* has a duration measured in rounds. You cast it and each melee touch attack made thereafter inflicts Dex damage.

Comment: @JeorMattan Oh, right. Yes, I should cover that.

Comment: @JeorMattan That's not how [Duration](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#duration) works in this case: "If the spell affects creatures directly the result travels with the subjects for the spell’s duration." The spell *shivering touch* has *Target: Creature touched.* The spell's problem is that the spell *deals damage* (albeit ability damage), which makes a Duration of rounds meaningless. To make the spell follow the rules, the DM must house rule *either* the spell's duration to instantaneous *or* change the ability damage to a penalty.

Comment: @HeyICanChan riiight.

Comment: Can i do full attack of touch attacks?

Comment: @SPike86 I know it *seems* like it should be part of the answer KRyan supplied, but that's an interesting enough question to stand on its own. Touch attacks get weird.

Comment: @SPike86 Depends on the touch attack.

Comment: Spell Opportunity allows a spell to be cast in place of an attack - although that is an Epic Feat. Why mention wands? I am a little curious.

Comment: @Ruut Because that's what "trigger" means in 3.5, but on rereading I doubt that was what he meant

Answer (score -1):

## There is a lot to clarify

**Templates:**

Not very many templates add Hit Dice, so all that would do is increase your Challenge Rating and Effective Character Level.

**Monster Class:**

Only your levels with Hit Dice would count as a Character Level. Levels with no Hit Dice is "buying off your level adjustment" and only increase your Effective Character Level.

**Examples of Effective Character Level vs. Character Level:**

1. 5 Hit Die Monster with +5 Level Adjustment and 5 levels of Barbarian
   = *Effective Character Level 15* (5 levels of monster + 5 level adjustment + 5 levels of barbarian).
2. 5 Hit Die Monster with +5 Level Adjustment and 5 levels of Barbarian
   = *Character Level 10* (5 levels of monster + 5 levels of barbarian).

**Divine Power:**

Your Base Attack Bonus would be determined by how many hit dice you have from your combination of Template + Racial Hit Dice + Character Class.

If you are a Half-Vampire Minotaur with 8 levels of cleric, you would have 6 racial hit dice, and 8 levels of cleric. Your BAB would be +14 rather than +12.

---

**Shivering Touch:**

The controversy surrounding Shviering Touch, is the duration, and the high amount of ability damage with no saving throw.

**Duration:**

Does the spell allow you to keep dealing that damage 1 round per level? Does the spell automatically deal damage 1 round per level? Does the damage only last 1 round per level?

The way it is written (albeit poorly) it seems to allow you to keep making your touch attacks dealing 3d6 dexterity damage. Without allowing a saving throw, like other damaging spells so allow, that is rather very powerful for a 3rd level spell. DM's should either allow a saving throw or start introducing Cold Resistance/Immunities to prevent abuse.

Why is it so powerful? Without a way to resist cold or ability damage, you could very very quickly render people paralyzed (Dexterity: 0).

The way it was probably intended was as a penalty that lasts for the rounds indicated, similar to Ray of Enfeeblement - since that penalty doesn't allow a saving throw either. It is possibly, also, campaign specific. Since it came out in the Frostburn book, and many creatures have high cold resistance and cold immunity, it could mitigate possible abuse. There were ways to ensure that creatures even immune to cold would still take cold damage, but that implies a class or feat investment.

Metamagic feats, such as maximize spell, causing an unmitigated 18 points of dexterity damage could become very game hindering.

---

**Touch Attacks:**

> Some attacks disregard armor, including shields and natural armor. In these cases, the attacker makes a touch attack roll (either ranged or melee). When you are the target of a touch attack, your AC doesn’t include any armor bonus, shield bonus, or natural armor bonus. All other modifiers, such as your size modifier, Dexterity modifier, and deflection bonus (if any) apply normally.

Touch attacks, as an attack roll, would be allowed to be iterive, based upon your Base Attack Bonus. Perfect example of this, is a trip attack.

> You can try to trip an opponent as an unarmed melee attack.
>   Make an *unarmed melee touch attack* against your target. This provokes an attack of opportunity from your target as normal for unarmed attacks.
>
> Some weapons can be used to make trip attacks. In this case, you make a *melee touch attack* with the weapon instead of an unarmed melee touch attack, and you don’t provoke an attack of opportunity.

But not all touch attacks, such as spells, especially those as spells or spell-like abilities are allowed to be iterative, because the spell itself is a standard action (and most times the duration is instantaneous). Inflict Light Wounds is a perfect example.

> Casting Time: 1 standard action
>   Range: Touch
>   Target: Creature touched

**Conclusion:**

Only touch attacks would allow Shivering Touch to take effect. If you have a means of channeling a spell through a weapon, such as a Spellsword, Duskblade, etc.; then you wouldn't be confined to touch attacks - or unarmed strikes.

**Commentary:**

As previously stated in this answer, the spell is written poorly and could be misconstrued very easily. The spell is simply flawed. I, as a DM, do not allow it. Your DM needs to modify it (if he has some sanity) to fit within parameters of other touch attack spells. A good model would be [Chill Touch](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Chill_Touch). Allowing one touch attack a round, for the number of rounds listed, and a Fortitude save for half damage, could balance the spell out a little more. As it is right now, a *Maximized Empowered* Shivering Touch (causing 27 Dexterity damage with no saving throw) will get DMG's thrown at you.

Comment: While the question arguably *does* ask all of these questions, I’d argue they probably shouldn’t be all in one question and that therefore answers should stick to the primary question as much as possible. That’s debatable. But the statements you make about *shivering touch*, those I do strongly disagree with: you can’t say what the duration means, because it’s inherently nonsensical in that situation. Guesses like yours don’t *actually* make sense, and all contradict how the rules actually work in various ways.

Comment: @KRyan Let's head to chat.

Comment: @KRyan That spell has entire forum threads about it. Without errata there is no way in knowing what the writer's mind was at. Stating the questions are exactly what many people ask. Writing "it seems" is a very literal reading of the way the spell is written. Writing "if your DM allows" implies that his DM has made a decision based on the spell. I simply don't see what you are seeing in what I wrote. I honestly believe you are digging too deep.