# Instantaneous multiple hit cleric spells

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, cleric

Now that I know [how an instantaneous spell can allow multiple attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/144437/9552), I want some for a future Sacred First.

Unfortunately I could only find Chill Touch and Parching Touch as *domain* spells, so limited in usage.

Are there similar, official Cleric spells available on Eberron?

Comment: @HeyICanChan official please

Comment: Does Anyspell count? From the spell domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If *Chill Touch* (cold domain) and *Parching Touch* (Thirst Domain) are good enough (or another one from another domain) for you you could:**

Use the Alternative class Feature for Cleric (PHBII) *Spontaneous Domain Casting* to do it as much times as slots of these levels that you possess if you have the specific domain.

> ### Spontaneous Domain Casting
>
> After a while, clerics can start looking very similar. Even with a variety of domains to choose from, domain spells take up such a small portion of the average cleric’s repertoire that they don’t have much effect on the overall feel of the character. With spontaneous domain casting, though, your domain choice becomes a more important element of your character. You won’t be able to provide as much healing to your party as a typical cleric, but the ability to prepare *cure* or *inflict* spells in your domain spell slots keeps you from falling too far behind in that area.
>
> **Level:** 1st
>
> **Replaces:** If you select this class feature, you do not gain the ability to spontaneously convert prepared spells into *cure* or *inflict* spells.
>
> **Benefit:** You can convert stored spell energy into the spells of one of your domains. Pick one of your two domains. You can “lose” any prepared spell (other than a domain spell) to cast any spell of the same level or lower on that domain list. Your choice is permanent unless an alignment change, deity change, or other dramatic event leaves you incapable of accessing the domain.
>
> In addition, when preparing spells you can choose to fill any or all of your domain spell slots with either *cure* or *inflict* spells (depending on whether you would normally convert prepared spells to *cure* or *inflict* spells) of the same level.

<sup>(*Player's Handook II* p. 37)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The only spells I can find with this feature:

| Spell | Level | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *Chill touch* | 1. Cold, death master, dread necromancer, duskblade, sha’ir, sorcerer, Telflammar shadowlord, warmage, wizard Blighter | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *Corrosive grasp* | 1. Sorcerer, wizard | *Spell Compendium* |
| *Handfire* | 1. Cleric, druid, Harper scout, hathran, ranger (each of Selûne) | *Magic of Faerûn* |
| *Handfire* | 1. Initiate of Selûne | *Player’s Guide to Faerûn* |
| *Parching touch* | 1. Sorcerer, thirst, wizard | *Sandstorm* |
| *Storm touch* | 5. Sorcerer, wizard | *Magic of Eberron* |
| *Scalding touch* | 7. Sorcerer, wizard | *Magic of Eberron* |
| *Touch of the grave* | 8. Sorcerer, wizard | *Complete Mage* |

#### *Handfire*

You’ll note that *handfire* is the only one available as a cleric spell, whether the *Magic of Faerûn* version that is just a cleric spell (but only for clerics of Selûne), or the *Player’s Guide to Faerûn* version that requires the Initiate of Selûne feat (which requires being a cleric, druid, hathran, or ranger of Selûne).

Note that *Eberron Campaign Setting* claims, as the first of the “Ten Things You Need to Know” on page 8, that “**If it exists in D&D, then it has a place in Eberron**,” (emphasis original). As *handfire* exists in D&D, it therefore has a place in Eberron. Where that place is, of course, is left undefined and up to your DM, but you can ask your DM about how it might be accessed—maybe it’s a cleric spell, maybe just for certain clerics, as in the *Magic of Faerûn* version, or maybe, like *Player’s Guide to Faerûn*, you need to take some Initiate feat. Eberron doesn’t have any distinctly moon-themed deities, but of course the moons are a **very** big deal in Eberron, and totally plausible as a focus of worship—after all, many druids and rangers in the Eldeen Reaches do. *Handfire* itself would also be **exceptionally** fitting for the Church of the Silver Flame, as would most of the rest of the Initiate of Selûne spells if you file off the moon theming (e.g. *argent blade*, *wall of silver*, *argent path*, *argent shield*)—aside from *strength of the beast*, which would need to be replaced as that one doesn’t fit the Silver Flame **at all.**

#### Domain spells

As you note in your question, *chill touch* and *parching touch* are on the cold and thirst domains, respectively. As [Maxime Cuillerier’s fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/161266/4563) points out, *Player’s Handbook II* has a spontaneous domain spells option for clerics to make those far more accessible. There are also other, similar, though weaker, options:

- The Domain Spontaneity feat from *Complete Divine*, burn a use of turn/rebuke undead to swap a spell for a domain spell of the spell’s level or lower.
- A 10,000-gp *domain icon* wondrous item from *Faiths of Eberron*, 3/day swap a spell for a domain spell of the spell’s level or lower. Doesn’t actually require that you have the domain in question, just that you worship a faith that offers it. Could get multiple for more uses per day, or arguably, per [the magic item creation guidelines](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm), could get a custom one with unlimited uses per day for 16,667 gp.
- A 36,000-gp *domain staff* from *Complete Champion*, 1/day per spell level swap a spell for a domain spell of that level. Overpriced and not recommended.

#### Other options

*Complete Mage* allows a cleric to be a divine magician: sacrifice a domain in order to pick one abjuration, divination, or necromancy wizard spell per spell level to add to your cleric list. That could let you get either *chill touch* or *parching touch* (*parching touch* is much better, as desiccation damage carries an automatic fatigue rider), as well as *touch of the grave* much later on (*corrosive grasp* is a conjuration, *storm touch* and *scaling touch* are evocations).

There’s also the Extra Spell feat, from *Complete Arcane*. Nothing in the feat says you have to choose a spell from a spell list you actually have access to. Few DMs actually allow you to do that, though, either because they feel that’s imbalanced and just don’t allow it (which is fair, though I am not sure I agree), or because they’re convinced that the feat actually bars it somehow (the arguments for this are convoluted, and I personally find them unconvincing, but nonetheless they exist).

## Conclusion

Since the cold and thirst domains are pretty meh, divine magician may be better than spontaneous domain spells. Any of the other options are far pricier, requiring a feat or expensive magic items, unless your DM lets you just have *handfire* as clerics of Selûne could under *Magic of Faerûn* rules.

Comment: Well you did save me a lot of research what an awesome and complete answer, I knew about the feat but I learned a lot again thanks to @KRyan  the no1 of all time.  The divine magician is very interesting!

Comment: Divine Magician makes you lose a Domain for it so unless 1.Cold/Thirst aren't on his deities domain AND/OR that 2.he would need/like to spontaneously use cure/inflict spells of course your option is better,  but completely losing a domain vs having a bad one is worse if none of the criteria I said are met.

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier My point is that you lose a domain for nine spells of your choice—so basically, you lose the granted ability for whatever value you can get out of choosing your own spells instead of taking those on the list. Since cold and thirst are poor, both in their lists and in their granted abilities, it isn’t really hard to do much better. Good point about the limitations of one’s faith on your choices, though.

Comment: yeah I guess 9 wizard spells are better indeed.

Comment: I prefer to play a true neutral cleric without a deity to chose the domains of my choice.

Comment: but to be able to do it Spontaneously is something I wouldn't want to lose though, depends on the campaign settings and his role/build I guess.